# Recurrence Relation derivatives of $x^x$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I was recently trying to derive explicit formulas for the nth derivative of $f(x) =  x^x$ which boiled down to solving the following recurrence relation (or something similar if I have made algebraic mistakes, which is fairly likely, this is besides the point though; I don't care that much about the derivatives themselves):
$$\begin{Bmatrix}
n+1\\
k\\
\end{Bmatrix} = 
(1-k)\begin{Bmatrix}
n\\
k-1\\
\end{Bmatrix} 
+ \frac d{da}\begin{Bmatrix}
n\\
k-1\\
\end{Bmatrix}
+a\begin{Bmatrix}
n\\
k\\
\end{Bmatrix} $$ 
where the coefficient $\begin{Bmatrix}
n\\
k\\
\end{Bmatrix}$ corresponds to the coefficient for the $x^{x-k}$ term in the nth derivative of $x^x$. Each of these coefficients is a function of $a, n $ and $k$. I would like to find an explicit formula for $\begin{Bmatrix}
n\\
k\\
\end{Bmatrix}$. I also know that for $0>k>n$, $\begin{Bmatrix}
n\\
k\\
\end{Bmatrix}=0$, and that $\begin{Bmatrix}
n\\
0\\
\end{Bmatrix}=a^n$ (for all reasonable n, that is, non-negative integers). I believe this is sufficient (or perhaps even redundant or excessive) information for the solution of this problem. Unfortunately, I am unsure how to go about doing this...Thanks!

Comment: I believe that the explicit formulation you're looking for are the Stirling numbers of the first kind: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind. Can't quite remember though; it's been a few years since I reached that conclusion myself having worked on the same problem. It was either the numbers of the first or second kind.

Comment: I think it would be (or would be pretty close) if I were to remove the second term on the right hand side of the relation, but the presence of this additional term makes it different, I believe...